# Normalizing Disparity Image Using an Accelarator

Tags: swift, core-image, disparity-mapping

I have a disparity image and I am normalizing it using the sample code below but it is very slow.
I need to do it  using some accelerator like custom CIFilter or any other technique but I dont know how? I am currently running the code with CIContext() and it is running on CPU(not sure). Is there a way to run it on GPU and accelerate without custom CIfilter? 
Here is the current code:

```
extension CVPixelBuffer {

  func normalize() {

    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(self)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(self)

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(self, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

    let baseAddr = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(self)!
    let floatBuffer = unsafeBitCast(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(self), to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.self)

    var minPixel: Float = 1.0
    var maxPixel: Float = 0.0

    for y in 0 ..< height {
      for x in 0 ..< width {
        let pixel = floatBuffer[y * width + x]
        minPixel = min(pixel, minPixel)
        maxPixel = max(pixel, maxPixel)
      }
    }


    let range = maxPixel - minPixel

    for y in 0 ..< height {
      for x in 0 ..< width {
        let pixel = floatBuffer[y * width + x]
        floatBuffer[y * width + x] = (pixel - minPixel) / range
      }
    }

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(self, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the pixel values as `Float` values, so you could also use vDSP.

[`vDSP_minv`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450267-vdsp_minv) and [`vDSP_maxv`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450621-vdsp_maxv) compute the extrema, and:

```
floatBuffer[y * width + x] = (pixel - minPixel) / range
```

Can be replaced by [`vDSP_vasm`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1449773-vdsp_vasm?language=objc) (you'll need to multiply by the reciprocal of `range`).

It might also be useful to look at [`vDSP_normalize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450106-vdsp_normalize) which does this calculation:

```
            m = sum(A[n], 0 <= n < N) / N;
            d = sqrt(sum(A[n]**2, 0 <= n < N) / N - m**2);

            if (C)
            {
                // Normalize.
                for (n = 0; n < N; ++n)
                    C[n] = (A[n] - m) / d;
            }
```

Comment: I am taking this as a correct answer although no needed it anymore(I runned my code on real device with CIContext and it is fast enough). I will use your code if I need extra speed in the future. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, vImage is probably the best option. See Option 3 from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55434232/541016).

There are also ways to do that in Core Image. I would imagine using the `CIAreaMinMax` filter for getting the extrema and then using some clever blending for normalization. If you want I can elaborate on that.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Yes, would be very usefull if you give code example.

Comment: I tried to get it working with built-in CI filters but no luck so far. Using `vImage` or `vDSP` is most likely the faster option for your use case anyways.

Comment: Thank you. I will.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Accelerate Framework vDSP vector functions to normalize disparity. See a modified [PhotoBrowse](https://github.com/racewalkWill/PhotoBrowseModified) in gitHub for a working demo.

Here's the relevant code in two functions

```
extension CVPixelBuffer {
    func vectorNormalize( targetVector: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Float>) -> [Float] {
        // range = max - min
        // normalized to 0..1 is (pixel - minPixel) / range

        // see Documentation "Using vDSP for Vector-based Arithmetic" in vDSP under system "Accelerate" documentation

        // see also the Accelerate documentation section 'Vector extrema calculation'
        // Maximium static func maximum<U>(U) -> Float
        //      Returns the maximum element of a single-precision vector.

        //static func minimum<U>(U) -> Float
        //      Returns the minimum element of a single-precision vector.


        let maxValue = vDSP.maximum(targetVector)
        let minValue = vDSP.minimum(targetVector)

        let range = maxValue - minValue
        let negMinValue = -minValue

        let subtractVector = vDSP.add(negMinValue, targetVector)
            // adding negative value is subtracting
        let result = vDSP.divide(subtractVector, range)

        return result
    }

    func setUpNormalize() -> CVPixelBuffer {
        // grayscale buffer float32 ie Float
        // return normalized CVPixelBuffer

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(self,
                                     CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidthOfPlane(self, 0)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane(self, 0)
        let count = width * height

        let bufferBaseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(self, 0)
            // UnsafeMutableRawPointer

        let pixelBufferBase  = unsafeBitCast(bufferBaseAddress, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.self)

        let depthCopy  =   UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: count)
        depthCopy.initialize(from: pixelBufferBase, count: count)
        let depthCopyBuffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Float>(start: depthCopy, count: count)

        let normalizedDisparity = vectorNormalize(targetVector: depthCopyBuffer)

        pixelBufferBase.initialize(from: normalizedDisparity, count: count)
            // copy back the normalized map into the CVPixelBuffer

        depthCopy.deallocate()
//        depthCopyBuffer.deallocate()

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(self, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

        return self

    }

}
```